# how to access columns passed as an argument using the accessor $ inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Im using the mtcars database. below is the function i wrote to get all values that dosent match the pattern

```
    f<- function(df,colname,pattern) {
  match1 <- df %>% select(colname) %>% mutate(!!colname := str_detect(!! rlang::sym(colname),pattern))%>%filter(!! rlang::sym(colname) == "FALSE") 
  df[is.na(match1$colname)=='TRUE']
}
```

when I call the function `f(mtcars,"hp","110")` the last line `df[is.na(match1$colname)=='TRUE']`  dosent work. please suggest what I need to change here. I tried doing this without function like below and it works.

```
match1 <- mtcars %>% select(hp) %>% mutate(hp := str_match(hp,"110"))
mtcars[is.na(match1$hp)=='TRUE']
```

How can i do this inside the above function?

Answer (score 2):

If we are passing a string, use `[[`.  Note that the output from `str_detect` is a logical vector.   So, we don't need to quote the `TRUE/FALSE`.  If we want to do the reverse, just negate (`!`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
f<- function(df,colname,pattern) {
  match1 <- df %>% 
    select(all_of(colname)) %>%
    mutate(!!colname := str_detect(!! rlang::sym(colname),pattern))%>%
    filter(!(!! rlang::sym(colname))) 
    df[is.na(match1[[colname]]),]
}
```

Outside the function, `str_match` is used instead of `str_detect`

```
f<- function(df,colname,pattern) {
  match1 <- df %>% 
    select(all_of(colname)) %>%
    mutate(!!colname := str_match(!! rlang::sym(colname),pattern))
    df[is.na(match1[[colname]]),]
}
```

-testing

```
> f(mtcars, "hp", "110")
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710          22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Merc 280            19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1
Toyota Corona       21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1
Dodge Challenger    15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2
AMC Javelin         15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2
Camaro Z28          13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4
Pontiac Firebird    19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2
Fiat X1-9           27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1
Porsche 914-2       26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2
Lotus Europa        30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2
Ford Pantera L      15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4
Ferrari Dino        19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6
Maserati Bora       15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8
Volvo 142E          21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2
```

Comment: Could you please give some info on `!!` and `:=` in this context. An if I run the function (e.g. `f(mtcars, "hp", "110")`. I get ` [1] mpg  cyl  disp hp   drat wt   qsec vs   am   gear carb
<0 Zeilen> (oder row.names mit Länge 0)`?

Comment: @TarJae The output is from the second function.  The first function doesn't return anything because there was no `NA` (from `str_detect`) thus `is.na(..` returns all FALSE.  The `!!` is for evaluation and the `:=` is for assignment when we are passing an expression on the lhs

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Sorry realized just now. Many thanks!!!

Comment: I kept the first function just to show the issue in the OP's code.  Otherwise, that step is unnecessary